# How do I get emmet to add an attribute with a value into a div tag?

Tags: vim, zurb-foundation, emmet

I am using the *emmet.vim* plugin.

How do you write emmet shorthand to account for attributes with no values?

This is what I write:

```
div.contain-to-grid.sticky>nav.topbar[data-topbar]
```

This is what I want to happen:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
  <nav class="topbar" data-topbar></nav>
</div>
```

This is what I get:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
  <nav class="topbar" data-topbar=""></nav>
</div>
```

Instead of creating an attribute without a value:

**data-topbar**

it is creating an empty value:

**data-topbar=""**

Is there a work around for this? If not then I can live with it. It would be nice to know if it can be done. Thanks

Comment: While the documentation does not seem to reflect it, [this closed issue](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/160) indicates that support for boolean attributes has been added to Emmet with the syntax of `div[my-attribute.]`, which should expand to `<div my-attribute></div>`.  This worked for me in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour of Emmet-vim was changed to be as expected from [documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/):

> You don’t have to specify attribute values: `td[colspan title]` will
>   produce `<td colspan="" title="">` with tabstops inside each empty
>   attribute (if your editor supports them).

So no. You can follow this request here: [Attributes without values not being expanded](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/issues/218).

Possible crude workaround could be to change the line 220 in `autoload/emmet/lang/html.vim` from

```
let current.attr[atts] = ''
```

to

```
let current.attr[atts] = function('emmet#types#true')
```

Comment: Okay. That is good enough for me. Emmet saves enough time for me without this ability. thanks!

Comment: While the documentation does not seem to reflect it, [this closed issue](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/160) indicates that support for boolean attributes has been added to Emmet with the syntax of `div[my-attribute.]`, which should expand to `<div my-attribute></div>`.  This worked for me in Sublime Text.

Answer (score 1):

I just copy the comment by @Alexander Nied to make it more noticeable, which says

> While the documentation does not seem to reflect it, this closed issue indicates that support for `boolean attributes` has been added to Emmet with the syntax of `div[my-attribute.]`, which should expand to  This worked for me in Sublime Text

this work for me too, in `Intellij idea`

Answer (score 0):

As of today (Feb 17, 2023), you can expand `foo[bar.]` into `<foo bar></foo>`

So,

```
div.contain-to-grid.sticky>nav.topbar[data-topbar.]
```

will be expanded to

```html
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
    <nav class="topbar" data-topbar></nav>
</div>
```